# Rails: devise override create method and rendering errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, devise, fancybox, registration

I'm new to rails, and developing first application gets hard because you know things, but you don't know how to do them.

I set my registration form **in a box** which comes out like a popup using "fancy-box" jquery.
When some user fails to sign up, I want the page **to remain in the box** with validation errors, 
and when he signs up correctly I want to redirect him in the home page, but I can't do this:

My controller which overrides devise methods:

```
def setup
  @society = Society.new
end

# GET /resource/sign_up
def new
  super
end

# POST /resource
def create
  build_resource

  if resource.save
   if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
      expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
     respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    render action: new  
  end
end

protected

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  '/vetrina/index'  #my homepage
end
```

and the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @society, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <fieldset>

  #all the inputs are here

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', "#", :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Any help?

Comment: So basically, you have 2 questions. 1. How to remain in the popup when signing up fails and 2. How to close the popup and redirect the main page when signing up goes through. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but the first one is more important.